# Trigonometric problem involving 2 ships and bearing and distance

Tags: trigonometry

Hello im doing this problem ships $a$ and $b$, $100$ miles apart are traveling 60mph and 80 mph, respectively. At 12NN, the bearing of $A$ from B is $72^{\circ}$. Find the distance and bearing of B from A at 5:30PM. I understand what i need to do and i just need help if my illustration is correct here is my illustration 
[image: My illustration link here]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which direction are they traveling?

Comment: Hmm it was not stated in the problem :(

Comment: You need to know which direction the ships are traveling relative to each other in order to solve a problem like this.

Comment: see here for graph: http://revisionmaths.com/gcse-maths-revision/trigonometry/bearings

Answer (score 0):

Here is the general way to solve these questions:

Since you know the speed of each boat and the time that they have travelled since being however far they are from each other (In this case, 100 miles from each other at 72 degrees), then you can determine how far they would have travelled given a specified direction. You can then compare the x and y components in order to determine how far they are from each other. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Now we can have different directionsbut answers will remain constant. Hope you know why.so i am assuming a travels west while b travels south. So at $5:30pm$ a will have travelled $330m$ and b will have travelled $440m$ so we need $angleB$ . Let the new truangle formed be $A'OB'$ with $A'O=330,B'O=440 ,angleO=90degrees$ so we can get $B$ by $tanB$ so $tanB=\frac{330}{440}=\frac{3}{4}$ so $B=tan^{-1}\frac{3}{4}=37 degrees$ and $d=\sqrt{330^2+440^2}=\sqrt{30250}=550$ and its done so $\theta=37 degrees,d=550$. Hope its clear